# How to add parameters to html tag using typescript Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tooltip, element

I get an element of html:

```
eventRender(info){
    console.log(info.el);
  }
```

And this is output:

[image]

And I want to add these attributes: `tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." placement="top"`
which is looking like this in html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary mb-2"
        tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus."
        placement="top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
```

How to add attributes into html tag using this function?

```
eventRender(info){
  console.log(info.el);
}
```

Comment: When is `eventRender` called?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) in angular for setting attribute for dynamic element:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  add() {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.test.nativeElement, 'tooltip', 'Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.');
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.test.nativeElement, 'placement' , 'top');
  }
```

sample html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="add()">Add</button>
<br>
<button #test type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary mb-2">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
```

see [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/renderer2-example-4-c4ljea)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

.html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-secondary mb-2"
        [ngbTooltip]="info.tooltip"
        [placement]="info.placement">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
```

.ts

```
info = {
  tooltip : "Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.",
  placement:"top"
}
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ziynkq?embed=1&file=app/tooltip-basic.html)**